# Can you search backwards from an offset using a Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Given a string, and a character offset within that string, can I search backwards using a Python regular expression?

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to get a matching phrase at a particular offset within a string, but I have to match the first instance before that offset.

In a situation where I have a regex that's one symbol long (ex: a word boundary), I'm using a solution where I reverse the string.

```
my_string = "Thanks for looking at my question, StackOverflow."
offset = 30
boundary = re.compile(r'\b')
end = boundary.search(my_string, offset)
end_boundary = end.start()
end_boundary
```

Output:  33

```
end = boundary.search(my_string[::-1], len(my_string) - offset - 1)
start_boundary = len(my_string) - end.start()
start_boundary
```

Output: 25

```
my_string[start_boundary:end_boundary]
```

Output: 'question'

However, this "reverse" technique won't work if I have a more complicated regular expression that may involve multiple characters. For example, if I wanted to match the first instance of "ing" that appears before a specified offset:

```
my_new_string = "Looking feeding dancing prancing"
offset = 16 # on the word dancing
m = re.match(r'(.*?ing)', my_new_string) # Except looking backwards
```

Ideal output: feeding

I can likely use other approaches (split the file up into lines, and iterate through the lines backwards) but using a regular expression backwards seems like a conceptually-simpler solution.

Comment: Just FYI, `\b` matches (or, more accurately, *consumes*) zero characters, not one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using positive lookbehind to make sure there are at least 30 characters before a word:

```
# re like: r'.*?(\w+)(?<=.{30})'
m = re.match(r'.*?(\w+)(?<=.{%d})' % (offset), my_string)
if m: print m.group(1)
else: print "no match"
```

For the other example negative lookbehind may help:

```
my_new_string = "Looking feeding dancing prancing"
offset = 16
m = re.match(r'.*(\b\w+ing)(?<!.{%d})' % offset, my_new_string)
if m: print m.group(1)
```

which first greedy matches any character but backtracks until it fails to match 16 characters backwards (`(?<!.{16})`).

Comment: Thanks for the lookbehind tip. I'm still trying to adapt your example so that I can "seek backwards" through the string for a longer expression.

Comment: (.*ing) as in my edited question - if I were to seek backwards for an entire word ending in -ing from an offset.

Comment: @Irwin, added a solution to that example

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of python's regex engine's preference for greediness (sort of, not really), and tell it that what we want is *as many characters as possible, but no more than 30, then ...*.

An appropriate regex, then, can be `r'^.{0,30}(\b)'`. We want the start of the first capture.

```
>>> boundary = re.compile(r'^.{0,30}(\b)')
>>> boundary.search("hello, world; goodbye, world; I am not a pie").start(1)
30
>>> boundary.search("hello, world; goodbye, world; I am not").start(1)
30
>>> boundary.search("hello, world; goodbye, world; I am").start(1)
30
>>> boundary.search("hello, world; goodbye, pie").start(1)
26
>>> boundary.search("hello, world; pie").start(1)
17
```

Comment: +1. It works equally well for multi-character sequences; just change `(\b)` to `(\b\w+\b)`.  And you might want to adjust the limit to make sure the word starts *before* the cutoff, not right at it (e.g. `{0,29}` in this case).

Comment: oh, yes, that's an off-by-one to be aware of -- the regex I've given works for my statement of the problem, which is off by one, that is.