# Python Regular Expression searching backwards

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract a string from a directory like this:

```
my_new_string = "C:\\Users\\User\\code\\Python\\final\\mega_1237665428090192022_cts.ascii"
ID = '1237665428090192022'
m = re.match(r'.*(\b\w+%s)(?<!.{%d})' % (ID, -1), my_new_string)
if m: print m.group(1)
```

I need to extract 'mega' from the above `my_new_string`. At the moment the above just gets `mega_1237665428090192022` so how do I get it to ignore the ID number?

To be honest I don't understand how these expressions work, even after consulting documentation. 
What does the `r'` do? And how does the `?<!.{%d}` work?

edit: Thanks guys!

Comment: What is ``(?<!.{-1})`` supposed to be useful to ?

Comment: `(?<!...)` Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for `....` This is called a negative lookbehind assertion. In this case the character `.` after the `!` indicates anything, the `{-1}` is supposed to indicate the offset.. [python source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match), [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203604/can-you-search-backwards-from-an-offset-using-a-python-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, although I'm not sure you necessarily need a regex here. Here are some options:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> my_new_string = "C:\\Users\\User\\code\\Python\\final\\mega_1237665428090192022_cts.ascii"
>>> os.path.basename(my_new_string)
'mega_1237665428090192022_cts.ascii'
>>> basename = os.path.basename(my_new_string)
>>> basename.split('_')[0]
'mega'
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+', basename).group()
'mega'
```

I don't think you are looking for a negative lookahead assertion or a negative lookbehind assertion. If anything, you want to match if numbers DO follow. For example, something like this:

```
>>> re.match(r'.*?(?=[_\d])', basename).group()
'mega'
```

The r simply makes a raw string (so that you don't need to constantly escape backslashes, for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> m = re.match(r'.*\b(\w+)_(%s)(?<!.{%d})' % (ID, -1), my_new_string)
>>> m.groups()
('mega', '1237665428090192022')

>>> m.group(1)
'mega'
```